# Describing the action of this Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, visualization

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 &-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Then $A \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $ and $A \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $

My first thought is that this is a reflection, or some combination of reflections, but I can't quite concisely describe it.

For example for $\chi_1 = \{x_1 + x_2 = 1\}$ we find $A : \chi_1 \to \{x=1\}$ with the action visualized below:

[image]

And for $\chi_2 = \{x_1 - x_2 = 1\}$ we find $A : \chi_1 \to \{2x_2 + x_1 = 1\}$ with the action visualized below

[image]

We also see A acting on the unit balls:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If $V=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$ then $AV=-V$. Thus $A$ is the symmetry of axis $D_1=\mathbb{R}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ parallel to $D_2=\mathbb{R}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: It's a shearing action.

Comment: It's a shear matrix with determinant $-1$ so it includes a reflection as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of transformation is sometimes called an [oblique reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_reflection). For a point $(x_1,x_2)$, we can describe the corresponding output as follows.

Draw the line through $(x_1,x_2)$ parallel to the vector $(-1,2)$ (the eigenvector of $A$ associated with $-1$). The output is the point on this line whose distance from the $x_1$-axis (the line parallel to $(1,0)$, which is the eigenvector of $A$ associated with $1$) is the same as the distance of $(x_1,x_2)$ from the $x_1$-axis.

What makes this reflection "oblique" is the fact that $(-1,2)$, the "direction of reflection", is not orthogonal to $(1,0)$, the "axis of reflection".

Answer (score 1):

The matrix is the product $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\0 &-1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 &1\\0 &1\end{pmatrix}.$$

So it is a composition of a shearing and a reflection. But it is not a product of reflections (and rotations) because it does not preserve Euclidean lengths:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1 \\0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

[Here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Earchristian/notes/linear-algebra/linear-transformations-of-the-plane.pdf) you can find more info about linear transformations of $\Bbb R^2$.